# X are equivalent to Y in Z

Tags: comparatives, comparisons

I'm pretty new to English StackExchange, and English is not my first language, so I'm not even sure what tags to look for. So, I apologize if this has been discussed before.

I'm writing up a blog and somehow I got confused with the proper grammar for a sentence that compares one thing to another thing of a different category.  For example, I want to compare Dodge Chargers, the car, with Cheetahs, the animal. Which one is the proper sentence:

`Dodge Chargers are equivalent to Cheetahs in the animal kingdom.`

`Dodge Chargers are equivalent to Cheetahs in automobiles.`

Do I use the category from the first or second subject?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid ambiguity, use

> Dodge Chargers in automobiles are equivalent to
>   cheetahs in the animal kingdom.

In

> Dodge Chargers are equivalent to cheetahs in the animal kingdom

*in the animal kingdom* refers to cheetahs, while in

> Dodge Chargers are equivalent to cheetahs in automobiles

*in automobiles* refers to Dodge Chargers and may be seen as a rewriting of

> In automobiles, Dodge Chargers are equivalent to cheetahs.

Comment: So, what you are saying is that both are applicable?

Comment: I am just picturing those cheetahs behind the wheel in their automobiles...

Answer (score 3):

> *In the automobile world, Dodge Chargers are* ***the*** *equivalent* ***of*** *cheetahs in the animal kingdom*.

Answer (score 2):

> *Dodge Chargers are equivalent to cheetahs in automobiles.

has a (kind of silly) misplaced modifier, so it might be better to rewrite it with *in automobiles* in front, as Clark Kent did at the end of his answer.

For what it's worth, I would probably just write:

> Dodge Chargers are the cheetahs of the automobile world.

Answer (score 1):

Use the category from the second subject.  Essentially, you're using an analogy i.e.:

> Dodge Charger:cars::cheetah:animals

but omitting the first category.